# Using css child selector in ruby selenium-webdriver element find_elements

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, webdriver

I want to avoid using XPath where possible when finding elements in webdriver, but be able to reference child elements from already found elements e.g.

For the following html:

```
<div id="myelement">
    <table class="myclass">
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>something</td>
               <td>
                   <table>
                       <tbody>
                           ...
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               ...
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have a css expression:

driver.find_elements('div#myelement table.myclass > tbody > tr')

I want to break this up into the table element and the rows, without having to refer back to the table expression. e.g. for XPath:

```
table = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='myelement']//table[@classname='myclass']")

rows = table.find_elements(:xpath, 'tbody/tr')
```

I've tried the following, which works using JQuery $('div#myelement table.myclass').find('> tbody > tr')

```
table = driver.find_element(:css, 'div#myelement table.myclass')

rows = table.find_elements(:css, '> tbody > tr')
```

This causes an error `assert_ok': An invalid or illegal string was specified (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Removing the first '>' of course works, however means decendant tbody's are selected and not just immediate children.

How can I do this correctly using just css?

Comment: Does this `table.find_elements(:xpath, 'tbody/tr')` work?

Comment: Can you show your final purpose of the test?

Comment: As mentioned above, it works, but I'd prefer not to use xpath for one-off issues.

Comment: @BillyChan the only purpose is so I can wrap the table in a PageObject (or at least a widget), and have the object handle the fetching of rows. I'm not really using webdriver as a test, but a robot to pull data from a website.

Answer (score 5):

As you don't give the page url,I took this [Chinese language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language).Now I tried to find out the table column values for the second row of the first table having `class` name `"wikitable sortable`.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language"

table = driver.find_element(:css,"table.wikitable") # !> assigned but unused variable - table
tb_col = driver.find_elements(:css,"tr:nth-of-type(2)>td")
tb_col[0..5].each{|e| p e.text}
# >> "汉语／漢語 or 中文\nHànyǔ or Zhōngwén"
# >> "汉语"
# >> "中文"
# >> "Wu\nNotes: includes Shanghainese"
# >> "Wu; 吴/吳"
# >> "Wúyǔ"
```

The way you tried `table.find_elements(:css, '> tbody > tr')` is not valid css syntax in `selenium-webdriver`.It should be `table.find_elements(:css, 'tbody > tr')`.I would suggest you to write this way:

```
table = driver.find_element(:css, 'div#myelement table.myclass>tbody')
rows = table.find_elements(:css, 'tr')
```

or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qgd9M/)

```
table = driver.find_element(:css, 'div#myelement table.myclass')
rows = table.find_elements(:css, 'tbody:nth-of-type(1) > tr')
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, table.find_elements(:css, 'tbody > tr') will select descendants and not just children, e.g. there may be another table inside that table, which shouldn't also be selected.

Comment: try `driver.find_element(:css, 'div#myelement table.myclass>tbody')` and `table.find_elements(:css, 'tr')`

Comment: yes table.find_elements(:css, 'tbody:nth-of-type(1) > tr') will work I think, although not exactly the same meaning, but without me crawling webdriver server source to see if there's a way to have child selectors at the start, it's the best answer, so if you put that in a new answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @Andy which one you want me to put as an answer... I am confused :(

Comment: table.find_elements(:css, 'tbody:nth-of-type(1) > tr'), you removed it from your comments

Comment: yes, I tested it earlier, works fine. The first tbody of the table should always be the correct element, although I think it's possible semantically to have multiple tbody's as children, it's unlikely to happen. so I'm happy with the edited answer